# how to insert into mysql database from table in java GUI?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into mysql db from java GUI , however there is an exception stating

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySql server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?.?)' at
>   line 1

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ugc VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, univ_name.getText());
        pst.setString(2, reg_no.getText());
        pst.setString(3,affiliation);
        String naac_grade=naac.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pst.setString(4, naac_grade);
        pst.setString(5, country.getText());

        pst.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: are you sure the sql excuted is the above as you showed because exception says you have a dot before last `?` which is an error but in you code there is no dot

Comment: I have copy pasted the code

Comment: remove the parameters from `pst.executeUpdate(sql);` because you have already prepared the statement then there is no need to provide it again

Comment: Does you table has 5 columns ?? It not then this exception may arise.Add column name in the  after "insert into ugc"

Comment: yes it has, and if i use executeQuery() it gives me another exception , stating data manipulations are not allowed

Comment: Please provide your table structure here

Comment: (univ_name,reg_no,affiliation,naac_grade,country) it is

Comment: can you post the code and stacktrace of the data manipulation error

Answer (score 1):

When executing the PreparedStatement use

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

instead of

```
pst.executeUpdate(sql);
```